# How to structure the data flow of a React Application using useContext, so that I can handle the state of parent component from child components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I have just finished this blog post tutorial [ReactCalendarComponent](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/build-a-react-calendar-component-from-scratch/) and now I am trying to separate the long one page component that the tutorial provides into different components.
I am new to React so I start reading post about *which is the best way to handle data beetween parents and children components*; and I conclude that redux was to much for this proyect, so I try to only use react Hooks. (Correct me, please, if the decision was bad).
Finally I get to a Point that my Proyect is separated into differents components, but the parent continue to have all the functions that are related to the state and the child components.

*Parent component*

```
import MonthTable from "./components/MonthTable"
import YearTable from "./components/YearTable"
import DateTable from "./components/DateTable"
import ShowHeader from "./components/ShowHeader"
import moment from "moment";

const DateObjectContext = React.createContext();

const Calendar = () => {
    const weekdayshort = moment.weekdaysShort();
    const [dateObject, setDateObject] = useState(moment());
    const [allMonths, setAllMonths] = useState(moment.months());
    const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(0)
    const [showDateTable, setShowDateTable] = useState(true)
    const [showMonthTable, setShowMonthTable] = useState(false)
    const [showYearTable, setShowYearTable] = useState(false)

//Long list of functions that handles the child components and the state
//Here are some
let month = () => ( dateObject.format("MMMM") )

const handleShowYearTable = (e) => {
  if(showMonthTable === true){
    setShowYearTable(false)
  }else if(showDateTable === true){
    setShowDateTable(false)
  }
    setShowYearTable(true)
}


return (  
      <div className="tail-datetime-calendar">
          <DateObjectContext.Provider value={{
            month,
            showMonth,
            onPrev,
            onNext,
            handleShowYearTable,
            year,
          }}>
            <ShowHeader />
          </DateObjectContext.Provider>
          <div className="calendar-date">
            {
              <DateObjectContext.Provider
              value={{
               allMonths,
               setMonth,
               actualYear,
               setYear
              }}>
                {showYearTable && <YearTable props={year()}/>}
                {showMonthTable && <MonthTable />}
              </DateObjectContext.Provider>
            }
          </div>
          <div>
            <DateObjectContext.Provider
              value={{
                weekdayshort,
                daysInMonth,
                firstDayOfMonth,
                currentDay,
                onDayClick
              }}>
             {showDateTable && <DateTable />}
            </DateObjectContext.Provider>
          </div>  
      </div>    
     
    );
}
```

*Example of one child, ShowHeader*

```
const ShowHeader = () => {
    const { month,
            showMonth,
            onPrev,
            onNext,
            handleShowYearTable,
            year} = useContext(DateObjectContext)

    return (
        <div className="calendar-navi">
          <span 
              className="calendar-button button-prev"
              onClick={e => onPrev()}></span>
            <span 
              data-tail-navi="switch" 
              className="calendar-label"
              onClick={ e => {showMonth()} }>
              {month()}
            </span>
            <span 
              className="calendar-label"
              onClick={e => handleShowYearTable()}>
              {year()}
            </span>
            <span 
              className="calendar-button button-next"
              onClick={e => {onNext()}}></span>  
        </div>
    )
}
```

**My Question is: ¿How can I put the functions related to the child components inside each component?**

Comment: You only need ONE `DateObjectContext.Provider`.  Everything inside of it gets access to the context - children, grandchildren, etc.  However you don't really *need* the context at all.  You could just provide those values as props when you call `ShowHeader`.

Comment: But the problem is the dateObject state, wich changes from all children components. What I want to do is to put the functions that affect the dateObject from child componets in its respective place. For example: actually I have onPrev() function in the parent component, wich changes the dateObject. This function is called from ShowHeader and its passed to this component by DateObjectContext.Provider. But what I want is to have all the logic in the same component. I mean onPrev() inside ShowHeader. ¿How can I do that?